# JavaFX, custom value factory?

Tags: javafx

I would like to make a custom spinner, therefore I created a custom value factory. All I did as of now is copied DoubleSpinnerValueFactory from the SpinnerValueFactory class, renamed it and made it non-static, then added wrapValue function. However when I try to put it in my FXML instead of the double one, I get an error: sample.myValueFactory is not a valid property.

Can someone tell me why is this happening? Thanks.

Spinner in the fxml:

```
        <Spinner fx:id="spinnerRowCount" prefWidth="400.0" editable="true">
                        <valueFactory>
                            <sample.myValueFactory fx:id="spnRowCountValueFactory">
                                <min>0</min>
                                <max>100000</max>
                                <amountToStepBy>1</amountToStepBy>
                                <wrapAround>true</wrapAround>
                            </sample.myValueFactory>
                        </valueFactory>
       </Spinner>
```

Everything is in the sample package.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some code. A [MCVE] would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, however all I did was what I wrote.

Comment: Try naming your class according to the standard conventions (i.e. with the first letter capitalized). You may need to include an import, i.e. `<?import sample.MyValueFactory?>` and then use the simple class name.

Comment: Yeah, thanks the import did it. And not having capital letter was just silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html):

> an element's tag is considered an instance declaration if the tag begins with uppercase letter (and the class is imported)

whereas

> Elements whose tag names begin with a lowercase letter represent object properties.

So it is important to follow the usual Java naming conventions in your classes; i.e. make their names begin with a capital letter. Additionally, you should import the class:

```xml
<?import sample.MyValueFactory?>
```

and then

```xml
<valueFactory>
    <MyValueFactory fx:id="spnRowCountValueFactory">
```

etc